# How do I ignore a RedirectMatch .htaccess rule from a parent directory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've recently revamped my website so that it uses PHP for common elements. I then uploaded this .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)\.htm(l?)$ $1.php
```

to redirect requests for .htm or .html pages to the corresponding .php page. However, my host's stats manager, which is located in the /stats/ directory within my /public/ directory, uses .html pages, which now get redirected to .php pages, which don't exist and so return 404 errors. How do I set up .htaccess so as to not apply the redirect to pages within the /stats/ directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the redirect match (mod_alias) to use mod_rewrite instead, and then add a condition to exclude all `/stats/` requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stats/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ /$1.php [L,R=301]
```